# Is it okay to return an object in a list endpoint according to REST API specification?

Tags: design, rest, api

I need to add extra data to a list endpoint. Basically it is the list I want to return and an extra data. Like below

```
{
  "results": [...],
  "extra_data": {
    "field": "value"
  }
}
```

Is it okay to return this result from list endpoint or a detail endpoint?

Comment: Adding some metadata to a collection of resources is not uncommon, see this answer for example https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/415689/320517

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it okay to return an object in a list endpoint according to REST API specification?

Yes - REST doesn't constrain what the representation of a resource should be.

Remember: the reference implementation of the REST architectural style is the world wide web.  If you have a web page with a list of links, and you add additional information to that page, does the web still work?  Of course.

As a rule, both REST and HTTP do not constrain the design of resources and representations (beyond the fact that REST calls for using hypertext to control application state).