# JSON response of a service has value of property as either an object or array of the same type of objects, Does this negate some SE principle?

Tags: json, soa, reference

I am working with a provided end point that returns a JSON response,

Property "Items" in the response changes depending on:

When there is a single value being returned then it is an object

```
Items:{SomeObject}
```

same property when there are multiple items are being returned then it is an array of objects:

```
Items:[{SomeObject1},{SomeObject2},...,{SomeObjectn}]
```

I believe that this is not right, by that I mean in case of single object or no object being returned followings would be natural to be expected:

When No Object is being returned:

```
Items:[]
```

When one object is being returned:

```
Items:[{SomeObject1}]
```

When more than one object is returned:

```
Items:[{SomeObject1},{SomeObject2},...,{SomeObjectn}]
```

but I can't find the specific justification. I am not even sure what reference to look up, google searches have not yielded anything useful so far.

More reasoning as to why I think the existing behaviour is probably wrong:

1.Is by drawing analogy from any/all typed languages, ignore the union types e.g. variant, dynamic, etc. that do not define a single expected interface.

or

2.SQL database data select result return behaviour, where rows returned be 0 , 1 or n . No (sane?) SQL database would switch it's return datastructure for 1 or n rows

Besides type uniformity and consistency in behaviour that is to be expected from any system, I can not present any reason to the api development team that this implementation that returns non-uniform data type and is inconsistent behaviour to almost all the existing systems that one can think of.

Please note, I am not asking how to fix this, but why this implementation is wrong.

If same behaviour was implemented in a C#, Java or even JavaScript as the return value of a method I guess it would not be passing code review.

The best I can think of is that "type homogenity" is a principle in SE and databases implicitly implement it,

As per comment of @Ben Cottrell, that having variant types being is not uncommon in JSON : yes, but the same service in SOAP generates an XSLT that is consumable by client code generating tools, why have it implemented in such a way where as returning arrays of same types is cleaner and can be handled by client proxy code generation tools?

Comment: "I know that this is not right" what context does the tool have? If you just give it a document, how should it know which single items are correctly single items, and which are lists that so happen to be length 1?

Comment: I don't see any broken principles;  It seems that the field `Items` is merely represented by some kind of [Union Data Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) (or possibly a 'variant' data type) , which is not at all uncommon nor unreasonable in a JSON structure.

Comment: @BenCottrell : if it was always an array of 0,1 or many elements it would have make sense . If this was SOAP then no wsdl can be validated for it , In types systems this would not be even be possible let alone allowed. It just seems wrong but I yield to experts.

Comment: I think Caleth's comment reflects my concerns already. Context is king. Software engineering principles are not globally right or wrong, to assess them, one needs context.

Comment: somehow similar and related but not exactly same:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/415686/single-item-endpoint-responses-list-vs-object

Comment: Questions have a much better chance to get answers when they don't contain biased assumptions like "I know this is wrong, but I don't know why". I took the freedom to reword this a little bit, but I cannot guarantee this will be enough to convince enough community members to a reopening vote.

Comment: It’s a trivial problem. You read the item as a single item (an array is a single item). If it is not an array, then you replace it with an array with that single item. That’s done very low in the reader, the rest of the app doesn’t care. Same if your app expects a string and gets 123 instead of “123”: Turn it into a string at the lowest level (and complain to whoever created the JSON).

Comment: Representing an array of one item as the item itself is problematic in general since it can introduce ambiguities. For example what if you have an array of arrays or represent a tree as nested arrays? Even if it it unambiguous in this particular case I still think it is a bad idea to special-case 1-item arrays since it will complicate code and API for no particular benefit. Type unions (or sum types) has their place, but not as a way to complicate what can easily be represented as a single uniform type.

Comment: Not saying it’s a good idea. But I’ve worked with JSON where I could do nothing whatsoever about the format. The most genius move was someone moving a list of items to a dictionary using a totally pointless key with about 20 different values and returning it as an array. (WTF?). So if you asked about 1000 items you would only get the last one for every key, about 30. I figured that asking for 16 items there were usually only few duplicates removed, so I asked for a range of 16, figured which ones were missing, and asked for those individually.

Comment: @DocBrown : Thank you, regarding the part "I don't know why", suppose the question was about OOP and I said a subclass is hiding members that are public in the parent class. If I said there is something wrong with that, then you'd point me to Liskov substitution principle.
I am really looking for some relating principles that discuss this.
A better example would be , in C# if you had a method that returned maybe an Object or maybe an Array of that object then why would that be wrong? ( No way it would pass a code reviw).

Comment: @gnasher729 : if that was a method in a language like C++ , C# or Java that either returned a single object or array of those objects , although it might be trivial to handle, but it is not something that almost anyone does. I have no problem in handling it, but it is done over and over many services, and each time have to do the same stupid check, never seen this pattern of variation in return type anywhere.
Yes, it can be done and handled, but why? what benefit it has that having the same type being returned doesn't?

Comment: *"Besides type uniformity and consistency in behaviour that is to be expected from any system, I can not present any reason"* - yep, because there is no other reason. You are mainly used to strictly typed code, that's why you want to enforce this way of thinking to a JSON document. Others in your team may be more used to dynamic typing and think more liberal about this issue. Technically, both approaches will work, so this stays mainly opininionated.

Comment: @DocBrown: but that is exactly the point , the client is in C#, we are consuming the service in a typed language, we are the client for that service. The same way we provide the results in a format that the consumer wants it , we too want it in a way that makes it uniform for our consumption. Not matter of personal preference, it is matter of where the service is being consumed